# How to show Inputs Values in Object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to show all data `onChange` inputs in Object to post it in API in React and I tried the following:

```
import React, { useState} from "react";

const Counter = () => {
    const [form, setForm] = useState({});

    const FormData = (event, {name, value}) => {
        setForm({...form, [name]: value});
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input value={form.username || ''}  name="username" onChange={FormData} type="text"/>
            <input value={form.email || ''}  name="email" onChange={FormData} type="email"/>
            <input value={form.password || ''}  name="password" onChange={FormData} type="password"/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Counter;
```

But it shows issue `onChange` : `"Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'undefined' as it is undefined"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done as follows:

```
const Counter = () => {
const [form, setForm] = useState({});

const FormData = (event) => {
    const { target: { value, name } } = event;
    setForm({...form, [name]: value});
};

return (
    <div>
        <input value={form.username || ''}  name="username" onChange={FormData} type="text"/>
    // same for other inputs
    </div>
);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Umair , I need to know why it's work on this video : 14:27 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6IgQJG4XuE&list=PLx-q4INfd95FJ1pTWN7MImtHumkQx8Txc&index=7

Comment: On html input on onChange event second argument is not passed only event is passed as argument. He is using semantic UI form and its input it might be functionality of semantic UI that it adds second argument as in the video